# Removing \xf characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I am trying to remove all

```
\xf0\x9f\x93\xa2, \xf0\x9f\x95\x91\n\, \xe2\x80\xa6,\xe2\x80\x99t
```

type characters from the below strings in Python

```
    Text
  _____________________________________________________
"b'Hello! \xf0\x9f\x93\xa2 End Climate Silence is looking for volunteers! \n\n1-2 hours per week. \xf0\x9f\x95\x91\n\nExperience doing digital research\xe2\x80\xa6

"b'I doubt if climate emergency 8s real, I think people will look ba\xe2\x80\xa6 '

"b'No, thankfully it doesn\xe2\x80\x99t. Can\xe2\x80\x99t see how cheap to overtourism in the alan alps can h\xe2\x80\xa6"

"b'Climate Change Poses a WidelllThreat to National Security "

"b""This doesn't feel like targeted propaganda at all. I mean states\xe2\x80\xa6"

"b'berates climate change activist who confronted her in airport\xc2\xa0
```

The above content is in pandas dataframe as a column..

I am trying

```
string.encode('ascii', errors= 'ignore')
```

and regex but without luck. It will be helpful if I can get some suggestions.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew Yes working in python 3.x

Comment: I have input as string. But str object has no attribute 'decode'.

Comment: the dataframe named as new_data. So if we execute new_data['Text'].encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8') It's showing Attribute error: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current data in the question indicates you are using bytestring representations re-encoded as Unicode strings, and now you want to decode those bytestrings, but first, you need to encode the strings back to the bytestrings.

So, in your case, you can use

```py
x = "b""This doesn't feel like targeted propaganda at all. I mean states\xe2\x80\xa6"
x = x.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
print(x)
# => bThis doesn't feel like targeted propaganda at all. I mean states…
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/7VCzph).

Answer (score 1):

These are hexadecimal escape characters which arrives after encoding.
All occurences of type \x[AB] where A or B can be [`0123456789abcdefABCDEF`] can be considered of this form. Try using regex with a pattern.  **`\\x[0123456789abcdefABCDEF][0123456789abcdefABCDEF]`**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try decoding the bytes.

```
text=b'Hello! \xf0\x9f\x93\xa2 End Climate Silence is looking for volunteers! \n\n1-2 hours per week. \xf0\x9f\x95\x91\n\nExperience doing digital research\xe2\x80\xa6'.decode("utf8")
print(text) 
>> Hello!  End Climate Silence is looking for volunteers! 

1-2 hours per week.
```